# OpenGL texture upload: UNSIGNED_BYTE vs UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8

Tags: opengl, pixelformat

I'm calling glTexSubImage2D. If my pixel format is `GL_RGBA`, then are the pixel types `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` and `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8` fully equivalent?

Also, are these two pairs equivalent?

- `Format = GL_RGBA, Type = GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8`
- `Format = GL_BGRA, Type = GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV`

I've tried reading the OpenGL spec and the GL_EXT_packed_pixels spec, but honestly I can't make head or tail of them.

Answer (score 28):

The answers are No and No.  You have to think about the byte order in your computer.  If you have `GL_RGBA` and `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8`, that means that pixels are stored in 32-bit integers, and the colors are in the logical order RGBA in such an integer, e.g. the red is in the high-order byte and the alpha is in the low-order byte.  But if the machine is little-endian (as with Intel CPUs), it follows that the actual order in memory is ABGR.  Whereas, `GL_RGBA` with `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` will store the bytes in RGBA order regardless whether the computer is little-endian or big-endian.

`GL_BGRA` with `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV` would store colors in an integer in the logical order ARGB, but then on a little-endian machine, you get BGRA order in memory.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` and `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_...` in this example are the pixel transfer types. They do not say anything about how GL stores the color, only how the "packed" colors are interpreted by GL when the color data are sent to it. Sort of an important distinction because usually the goal with these more exotic formats is to match the client (CPU) and server (GPU) formats so that GL does not need to perform data conversion and can do a simple block transfer.

Answer (score 0):

See [JWWalker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7786405) first. This answer is a supplement to it. A quick illustration.

`GL_RGBA` stored in `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8`:

```
0xrrggbbaa
```

`GL_RGBA' stored in` GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`:

```
[0xrr, 0xgg, 0xbb, 0xaa]
```

In both cases, RGBA is in the logical order r, g, b, a, but on a little endian machine (this is the normal architecture), `0xrrggbbaa` has the little byte (least-significant) stored first. If you read the `uint32_t` one byte at a time, you'll get `0xaa` first! A C++ example:

```
uint32_t color{0x11223344};
uint8_t first_byte{reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(color)[0]};
```

`first_byte` will equal `0x44`.

One thing that's confusing is the word "first". It can mean "appearing first when written" as in "The red byte is first in 0xrrggbbaa". This is different from "having the lowest memory/pointer address" as in "The alpha byte is first in 0xrrggbbaa when encoded using little-endian"! When you use `GL_RGBA`, it sure looks like red will be first, but when encoded in a 4-byte integer little endian, it is only that way in the hex representation.