# Open GL - Why are Pixel values in ABGR and how to use them in RGBA

Tags: c++, opengl, pixelformat

I have some code for loading textures where I'm using DevIL to load the images and then OpenGL creates a texture from the pixels. This code works fine and the texture shows up properly and that's all fine.

Besides that I can also make an array from within the program to create the texture or make changes in the texture's pixels directly. My problem is here: when handling the pixels their format seems to be ABGR rather than RGBA as I would have liked.

I stumbled upon [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786187/opengl-texture-upload-unsigned-byte-vs-unsigned-int-8-8-8-8) that refers to the format that's passed in the glTexImage2D function:

*(...) If you have GL_RGBA and GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8, that means that pixels are stored in 32-bit integers, and the colors are in the logical order RGBA in such an integer, e.g. the red is in the high-order byte and the alpha is in the low-order byte. But if the machine is little-endian (as with Intel CPUs), it follows that the actual order in memory is ABGR. Whereas, GL_RGBA with GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE will store the bytes in RGBA order regardless whether the computer is little-endian or big-endian. (...)*

Indeed I have an Intel CPU. The images are loaded just fine the way things are right now and I actually use the GL_RGBA mode and GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE type.

```
GLuint makeTexture( const GLuint* pixels, GLuint width, GLuint height ) {

    GLuint texture = 0;

    glGenTextures( 1, &texture );

    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );

    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels );

    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );

    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, NULL );

    GLenum error = glGetError();
    if ( error != GL_NO_ERROR ) {
        return 0;
    }

    return texture;
}
```

This function is used in my two methods for loading textures, the method that loads an image from a file and the one that creates a texture from an array.

Let's say that I want to create an array of pixels and create a texture,

```
GLuint pixels[ 128 * 128 ];
for ( int i = 0; i < 128 * 128; ++i ) {
    pixels[ i ] = 0x800000FF;
}
texture.loadImageArray( pixels, 128, 128 );
```

By padding the pixels with this value I would expect to see a slightly dark red color.

```
red = 0x80, green = 0x00, blue = 0x00, alpha = 0xFF
```

But instead I get a transparent red,

```
alpha = 0x80, blue = 0x00, green = 0x00, red = 0xFF
```

Rather than using raw unsigned ints I made a structure to help me handling individual channels:

```
struct Color4C {
    unsigned char alpha;
    unsigned char blue;
    unsigned char green;
    unsigned char red;
    ...
};
```

I can easily replace an array of unsigned ints with an array of Color4C and the result is the same. If I invert the order of the channels (red first, alpha last) then I can easily pass 0xRRGGBBAA and make it work.

The easy solution is to simply handle these values in ABGR format. But I also find it easier to work with RGBA values. If I want to use hardcoded color values I would prefer to write them like 0xRRGGBBAA and not 0xAABBGGRR.

But let's say I start using the ABGR format. If I were to run my code in another machine, would I suddenly see strange colors wherever I changed pixels/channels directly?
Is there a better solution?

Comment: Problem in your understanding: `0xRR,0xGG,0xBB,0xAA` on your (Intel, little-endian) machine is `0xAABBGGRR`.  You've already found the information saying that `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` preserves the format of binary blocks of data across machines, while `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8` preserves the format of literals like `0xRRGGBBAA`.  Because different machines have different correspondence between binary and literals, **it is absolutely impossible for you to have both types of portability at once**

Comment: I see. Between preserving images and hardcoded literals I want to go with preserving image data since I'm mostly going to load images for my application. So then if I do write `0xAABBGGRR`, and that would actually be RGBA in my machine, running this code in another machine will show different results on-screen after all?

Comment: @aslg, yes because OpenGL will reinterpret it as `UNISGNED_BYTE`. C++ needs an endianess library, after all

Comment: Use shaders. Swizzle operations are cheap.

Comment: Also you can pass different formats to different function calls.

Comment: If you write `0xAABBGGRR` for a color in your code, you need to use `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV` as the type to be portable across different endianness. This is equivalent to `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` on little endian machines, but not on big endian.

Comment: I'm now passing the type as an argument using `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` for image loading and `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8` when directly accessing pixels. It seems to work well now.

Answer (score 1):

Promoting some helpful comments to an answer:

> `0xRR,0xGG,0xBB,0xAA` on your (Intel, little-endian) machine is `0xAABBGGRR`. You've already found the information saying that GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE preserves the format of binary blocks of data across machines, while `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8` preserves the format of literals like `0xRRGGBBAA`. Because different machines have different correspondence between binary and literals, it is absolutely impossible for you to have both types of portability at once. – Ben Voigt

> [Writing `0xAABBGGRR` would actually be RGBA in your machine, but running this code in another machine could show different results] because OpenGL will reinterpret it as `UNSIGNED_BYTE`. C++ needs an endianess library, after all. – WorldSEnder